# How to find rotated originX and originY

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry, trigonometry

#### Problem description with example

Let's say that at the beginning I have a group of 1 rectangle of size **50x50**. Top left corner of my group has following coordinates: `{ x: 0, y: 0 }`. Now I apply following operations:

- I perform rotation of my group by **90°** degrees what makes me to set `transform: rotate` with origin equal `{ originX: 25, originY: 25 }`. My whole group is rotated by **90°** from the center.
- I add the same **50x50** rectangle to my group **10** away from the lower edge of the first rectangle. This operation makes my whole group extend by gap size and size of added rectangle. In total my whole group has size is equal to **50x110** (2x rectangle 50x50 and 1x gap 50x10), but I do not change the rotation origin just to prevent this group to move right. I want to make this group to stay in previous position and I just want to add same rectangle on the end of this group.
- I would like to rotate my whole group to **0°**. The group should be rotated from the center of the rotated group. So, if top left coroner of my group has the following coordinates: `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` and the size of my rotated group is equal to **50x110** then to perform this rotation I should set origin to `{ originX: 25, originY: 55 }` (this is what I think, but I think I can be wrong). If I do what I have described above, then my whole group is going back to default position but is not rotated by **90°** degrees, what I do not want.

> The group position points never change, I only apply `transform: rotation(angle, originX, originY)` to see rotated group

#### Graphical representation of what I have described above

[image]

#### What I have currently achieved

```js
function degreesToRadians(angle) {
    return Number((angle * (Math.PI / 180)).toFixed(6));
}

function getRotatedCords(x, y, centerX, centerY, angleRad) {
    const rotatedX = centerX + (x - centerX) * Math.cos(angleRad) - (y - centerY) * -Math.sin(angleRad);
    const rotatedY = centerY + (x - centerX) * -Math.sin(angleRad) + (y - centerY) * Math.cos(angleRad);

    return {
        x: rotatedX,
        y: rotatedY,
    };
}

function getRectangleCenter({ topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight }) {
    const centerX = (topLeft.x + topRight.x + bottomLeft.x + bottomRight.x) / 4;
    const centerY = (topLeft.y + topRight.y + bottomLeft.y + bottomRight.y) / 4;

    return {
        x: centerX,
        y: centerY
    };
}

class RectangleGroup {
    constructor(wrapper) {
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
        this.setDefaults();
    }

    get groupWidth() {
        return this.count * this.singleRectangleWidth + (this.count - 1) * this.gapSize;
    }

    get groupHeigth() {
        return this.singleRectangleWidth;
    }

    get groupCoordinates() {
        let topLeft = {
            x: this.position.x,
            y: this.position.y
        }
        let topRight = {
            x: topLeft.x + this.groupWidth,
            y: topLeft.y
        };
        let bottomLeft = {
            x: topLeft.x,
            y: topLeft.y + this.groupHeigth
        };
        let bottomRight = {
            x: topRight.x,
            y: bottomLeft. y
        };
        if(this.rotation.angleDeg !== 0) {
            const angleRad = degreesToRadians(this.rotation.angleDeg);

            topLeft = getRotatedCords(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, this.rotation.originX, this.rotation.originY, -angleRad);
            topRight = getRotatedCords(topRight.x, topRight.y, this.rotation.originX, this.rotation.originY, -angleRad);
            bottomLeft = getRotatedCords(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, this.rotation.originX, this.rotation.originY, -angleRad);
            bottomRight = getRotatedCords(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y, this.rotation.originX, this.rotation.originY, -angleRad);
        }
        return {
            topLeft,
            topRight,
            bottomLeft,
            bottomRight
        };
    }

    setDefaults() {
        this.count = 1;
        this.singleRectangleWidth = 50;
        this.gapSize = 10;
        this.position = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
        this.rotation = {
            angleDeg: 0,
            originX: 25,
            originY: 25
        }
        this.group = this.createGroup();
    }

    createGroup() {
        const group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
        group.append(this.createRectangle(this.position.x, this.position.y));
        return group;
    }

    createRectangle(x, y) {
        const rectangle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
        rectangle.setAttribute('width', this.singleRectangleWidth.toString());
        rectangle.setAttribute('height', this.singleRectangleWidth.toString());
        rectangle.setAttribute('x', x.toString());
        rectangle.setAttribute('y', y.toString());
        return rectangle;
    }

    attach() {
        this.wrapper.append(this.group);
    }

    detach() {
        this.group.remove();
    }

    addRectangle = () => {
        const newX = this.count * this.singleRectangleWidth + this.gapSize;
        const newy = 0;
        this.group.append(this.createRectangle(newX, newy));
        this.count += 1;
    }

    setRotation = (angleDeg) => {
        const {x: originX, y: originY} = getRectangleCenter(this.groupCoordinates);
        this.rotation.angleDeg = angleDeg;
        this.rotation.originX = originX;
        this.rotation.originY = originY;
        this.group.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${angleDeg}, ${originX}, ${originY})`);
    }

    resetDefault = () => {
        this.detach();
        this.setDefaults();
        this.attach();
    }
}

const drawing = document.querySelector('.drawing');
const step1Btn = document.querySelector('.step-1');
const step2Btn = document.querySelector('.step-2');
const step3Btn = document.querySelector('.step-3');
const rectangleGroup = new RectangleGroup(drawing);
rectangleGroup.attach();
step1Btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    rectangleGroup.resetDefault();
    rectangleGroup.setRotation(90);
});
step2Btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    rectangleGroup.resetDefault();
    rectangleGroup.setRotation(90);
    rectangleGroup.addRectangle();
});
step3Btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    rectangleGroup.resetDefault();
    rectangleGroup.setRotation(90);
    rectangleGroup.addRectangle();
    rectangleGroup.setRotation(0);
});
```

```html
<!-- Set rotation 90 -->
<button class="step-1">Set step 1</button>
<!-- Set rotation 90 and add rectangle in the end of group -->
<button class="step-2">Set step 2</button>
<!-- Set rotation 90, add rectangle and set back rotation to 0 -->
<button class="step-3">Set step 3</button>
<svg class="drawing"></svg>
```

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to concatentate the translations instead of trying to reset the transform.

**After step 1**

```
<g transform="rotate(90, 25, 25)">
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0"/>
</g>
```

**After step 2**

```
<g transform="rotate(90, 25, 25)">
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0"/>
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="60" y="0"/>
</g>
```

**After step 3**

```
<g transform="rotate(-90, 25, 55) rotate(90, 25, 25)">
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0"/>
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="60" y="0"/>
</g>
```

*Note that the second rotation needs be listed first here.*

---

Another solution is to wrap the last step in a group whenever you want to modify the transform

**After step 1**

```
<g transform="rotate(90, 25, 25)">
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0"/>
</g>
```

**After step 2**

```
<g>
  <g transform="rotate(90, 25, 25)">
    <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0"/>
  </g>
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="60"/>
</g>
```

*Note the position of the second rectangle is different here.  It is positioned in the place you visually want it to be.  You don't need to compensate for the first rotation.*

**After step 3**

```
<g transform="rotate(-90, 25, 55)">
  <g transform="rotate(90, 25, 25)">
    <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0"/>
  </g>
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="60"/>
</g>
```

Comment: what do you think about solution I have posted to also keep extended rotated shape position. Is it good, or maybe there are better ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Checking first solution of @Paul LeBeau I also came up with some idea of achieving this in a bit different way, which will also allow get coordinates of extended and rotated shape. So, after you rotate base shape and extend it size you need to:

1. Get the coordinates of rotated shape (the real one that user see on canvas)
2. Then you need to get rotated shape center using coordinates from prev step
3. Then you need to calculate new top-left corner coordinates using rotated top-left coordinates calculated in 1 step and rotated shape center calculated in 2 step
4. Then you have to update position and rotation of the group (class data)
5. Then you have to destroy all children of the group, re-render all rectangles and apply new rotation on group.

I know that the last step can be costly, but this is a manual user update that doen't happen in every 1ms, so I think it should not be a problem in terms of performance). If angle is different but originX and originY is the same then you do not need to re-render all rectangles, applying only new rotation should be enough. This can be use-full if you have a kind of rotator attached to the group.

**Code fragment of angle update**

```js
setRotation = (angleDeg) => {
  const realCords = this.getGroupCoordinates();
  const { x: originX, y: originY } = getRectangleCenter(realCords);
  const angleRad = degreesToRadians(this.rotation.angleDeg);
  const newTopLeft = getRotatedCords(realCords.topLeft.x, realCords.topLeft.y, originX, originY, angleRad);
  this.position = newTopLeft;
  this.rotation.angleDeg = angleDeg;
  this.rotation.originX = originX;
  this.rotation.originY = originY;
  this.destroyRectangles();
  this.createRectangles();
  this.group.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${angleDeg}, ${originX}, ${originY})`);
}
```

**Working example**

```js
function degreesToRadians(angle) {
  return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function getRotatedCords(x, y, centerX, centerY, angleRad) {
  const rotatedX = centerX + (x - centerX) * Math.cos(angleRad) - (y - centerY) * -Math.sin(angleRad);
  const rotatedY = centerY + (x - centerX) * -Math.sin(angleRad) + (y - centerY) * Math.cos(angleRad);

  return {
    x: rotatedX,
    y: rotatedY,
  };
}

function getRectangleCenter({ topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight }) {
  const centerX = (topLeft.x + topRight.x + bottomLeft.x + bottomRight.x) / 4;
  const centerY = (topLeft.y + topRight.y + bottomLeft.y + bottomRight.y) / 4;

  return {
    x: centerX,
    y: centerY
  };
}

class RectangleGroup {
  constructor(wrapper) {
    this.wrapper = wrapper;
    this.setDefaults();
    this.group = this.createGroup();
  }

  get groupWidth() {
    return this.count * this.singleRectangleWidth + (this.count - 1) * this.gapSize;
  }

  get groupHeigth() {
    return this.singleRectangleWidth;
  }

  setDefaults() {
    this.count = 1;
    this.singleRectangleWidth = 50;
    this.gapSize = 10;
    this.position = {
      x: 50,
      y: 50
    }
    this.rotation = {
      angleDeg: 0,
      originX: 75,
      originY: 75
    }
    this.group = this.createGroup();
  }

  createGroup() {
    const group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
    group.append(this.createRectangle(this.position.x, this.position.y));
    return group;
  }

  createRectangle(x, y) {
    const rectangle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
    rectangle.setAttribute('width', this.singleRectangleWidth.toString());
    rectangle.setAttribute('height', this.singleRectangleWidth.toString());
    rectangle.setAttribute('x', x.toString());
    rectangle.setAttribute('y', y.toString());
    return rectangle;
  }

  createRectangles() {
    this.destroyRectangles();
    let x = this.position.x;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.count; i += 1) {
      this.group.append(this.createRectangle(x, this.position.y));
      x += this.singleRectangleWidth + this.gapSize;
    }
  }

  destroyRectangles() {
    this.group.childNodes.forEach(rectangle => {
      rectangle.remove();
    });
  }

  getGroupCoordinates() {
    let topLeft = {
      x: this.position.x,
      y: this.position.y
    }
    let topRight = {
      x: topLeft.x + this.groupWidth,
      y: topLeft.y
    };
    let bottomLeft = {
      x: topLeft.x,
      y: topLeft.y + this.groupHeigth
    };
    let bottomRight = {
      x: topRight.x,
      y: bottomLeft.y
    };
    if (this.rotation.angleDeg !== 0) {
      const angleRad = degreesToRadians(this.rotation.angleDeg);

      topLeft = getRotatedCords(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, this.rotation.originX, this.rotation.originY, -angleRad);
      topRight = getRotatedCords(topRight.x, topRight.y, this.rotation.originX, this.rotation.originY, -angleRad);
      bottomLeft = getRotatedCords(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, this.rotation.originX, this.rotation.originY, -angleRad);
      bottomRight = getRotatedCords(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y, this.rotation.originX, this.rotation.originY, -angleRad);
    }
    return {
      topLeft,
      topRight,
      bottomLeft,
      bottomRight
    };
  }

  attach() {
    this.wrapper.append(this.group);
  }

  detach() {
    this.group.remove();
  }

  addRectangle = () => {
    const newX = this.position.x + this.gapSize + this.count * this.singleRectangleWidth;
    const newy = this.position.y;
    this.group.append(this.createRectangle(newX, newy));
    this.count += 1;
  }

  setRotation = (angleDeg) => {
    const realCords = this.getGroupCoordinates();
    const { x: originX, y: originY } = getRectangleCenter(realCords);
    const angleRad = degreesToRadians(this.rotation.angleDeg);
    const newTopLeft = getRotatedCords(realCords.topLeft.x, realCords.topLeft.y, originX, originY, angleRad);
    this.position = newTopLeft;
    this.rotation.angleDeg = angleDeg;
    this.rotation.originX = originX;
    this.rotation.originY = originY;
    this.destroyRectangles();
    this.createRectangles();
    this.group.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${angleDeg}, ${originX}, ${originY})`);
  }

  resetDefault = () => {
    this.detach();
    this.setDefaults();
    this.attach();
  }
}

const drawing = document.querySelector('.drawing');
const step1Btn = document.querySelector('.step-1');
const step2Btn = document.querySelector('.step-2');
const step3Btn = document.querySelector('.step-3');
const rectangleGroup = new RectangleGroup(drawing);
rectangleGroup.attach();
step1Btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rectangleGroup.resetDefault();
  rectangleGroup.setRotation(90);
});
step2Btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rectangleGroup.resetDefault();
  rectangleGroup.setRotation(90);
  rectangleGroup.addRectangle();
});
step3Btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rectangleGroup.resetDefault();
  rectangleGroup.setRotation(90);
  rectangleGroup.addRectangle();
  rectangleGroup.setRotation(0);
});
```

```html
<!-- Set rotation 90 -->
<button class="step-1">Set step 1</button>
<!-- Set rotation 90 and add rectangle in the end of group -->
<button class="step-2">Set step 2</button>
<!-- Set rotation 90, add rectangle and set back rotation to 0 -->
<button class="step-3">Set step 3</button>
<svg class="drawing" width="200" height="200"></svg>
```